# How to close a branch by default after a pull request has been merged in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

By default a branch will remain in Bitbucket when a Pull Request (PR) has been merged. How to ensure that a branch will be removed after a PR has been removed?

[image]

When the option is enabled then the branch will be removed after the merge of a PR, but how to ensure that it is clicked by default to prevent that creators of the PR forget to click it and the branch remains in bitbucket?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/15300  Please vote for this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently selecting the `Close branch` option in the very dialogue illustrated in your question will actually delete the branch as well. From 
[Why only "Close" a branch instead of "Delete" it?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Why-only-quot-Close-quot-a-branch-instead-of-quot-Delete-quot-it/qaq-p/417416):

> Ben Tatham Jun 15, 2014
>
> It seems that I was mistaken. Marking a pull request to *Close branch
>   when merged*, does indeed Delete it. I'm not sure why they use
>   different language for that though.

Comment: Could it be selected by default? I would like to avoid that people have to select it because I see that they forget to click it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. AFAIK there isn't such options. Maybe it's worthy filing a feature request for it? See [New features policy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/new-features-policy-776640886.html)

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10344 created

Comment: It was moved to https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/15300

Answer (score 6):

What I really want is to add a comment to the accepted answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. So I'll note it here. I've closed BSERV-10344 because it's in the wrong tracker. This question is about Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org), not Bitbucket Server (the behind-the-firewall version). The correct issue tracker for the feature request is at https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues.

Also, re: "I'm not sure why they use different language for that", it's because Bitbucket Cloud supports Mercurial as well as Git. In Mercurial it's not possible to delete a named branch; they can only be closed. Since its support for Mercurial predates its support for Git, the terminology used is to "close" the branch.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/15300

Answer (score 4):

For Bitbucket Server you can set this up on a project or repo-level under Settings > Branches (under the Workflow section), scroll to the bottom and tick this setting on and press save:

[image: branch-deletion-on-merge-setting]

So all in all you have two options:

1. Change this setting on a project-level and have all repos under it inherit the project's settings by default
2. Change this setting on a repo-level (if you want only some of your repos to adhere to this)

Comment: For Bitbucket Cloud, I developed this [Open-Source extension](https://github.com/hmartos/bitbucket-pull-request-auto-delete-branch), which you can install from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bitbucket-pull-request-au/iffllgmebelmfdfiiagjgbpjhplobfem)